# FastAPI: Add description to a class based request parameter / filter

Tags: python, swagger-ui, fastapi, pydantic

I'm using this model class that specifies the different input parameters one can use to filter a result list of an endpoint:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class MyFilter(BaseModel):
    status: Optional[ValidationStatus]
    reference: Optional[str]
    include_documents: Optional[bool]
```

Same as for my input model fields I would like to add description strings to the SwaggerUI to explain the meaning e.g. specifically for `include_documents`.

My endpoint looks like:

```
def get_list(
    request: Request, my_filter: MyFilter = Depends(), db: Session = Depends(get_db)
):
```

I see in the docs only that a description is possible using `Query` for a parameter overall but not how I would do it for each "field" in my model. Is that possible?

When I try `Query` or `Path` in my method signature I get the error message:  `Param: my_filter can only be a request body, using Body()`

Comment: Have you already checked the docs? https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-fields/ is that the case?

Comment: @Isabi if I understand it correctly with Body() the parameters will need to be sent in the request body, while I want them to be url parameters, like ?include_documents=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution/workaround in a github issue of fastapi: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/4700

This works for me:

```
from fastapi import Query

class MyFilter(BaseModel):
    include_documents: Optional[bool] = Query(Query(description="hello", default=None))
```

Note: Without `default=None` it will be marked as required despite the `Optional`.

Answer (score 1):

For documenting `query parameters` in `OpenAPI`, there's an extra section dedicated to this part

https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/#declare-more-metadata

The `Query` object has to be used. With the parameters `title` and `description`, the necessary documentation will be provided to the consumers of the API.

Here's the example for python 3.10 taken from the official documentation.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Query

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/items/")
async def read_items(
    q: str
    | None = Query(
        default=None,
        title="Query string",
        description="Query string for the items to search in the database that have a good match",
        min_length=3,
    )
):
    results = {"items": [{"item_id": "Foo"}, {"item_id": "Bar"}]}
    if q:
        results.update({"q": q})
    return results
```

UPDATE 12/08/2022
Ok, I didn't get exactly the question. After the comment, now I get it.

The idea is the same, only applied to the `pydantic` model as described in https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-fields/#import-field

Here the example taken from the docs

```
class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str
    description: str | None = Field(
        default=None, title="The description of the item", max_length=300
    )
    price: float = Field(gt=0, description="The price must be greater than zero")
    tax: float | None = None
```

Comment: I have seen this example in the docs, but it only shows how it is done for a single parameter, not a filter model like in my question.

Comment: @djangonaut See updated answer

Comment: appreciate your help, but `Body()` is for requiring request body data, not for specifying url parameters.

Comment: You're using a `GET` request. Then no, it's not possible to have a pydantic model as `GET` parameter. You could write a `dependency` injection that reads the data and then fills it into the pydantic model. Otherwise I have no clue